# eSign/Electronic Signature API recommendations

Tags: .net, web-services, docusignapi, electronic-signature

I am exploring various esign APIs (docusign, esignature.io, etc) but I cant find one that fits my needs.

We want to implement esign into our software. Our software is sold as a SaaS and used by our clients at their own locations. We host our software internally and clients connect via hosted RDP sessions.

I need the following:

- Low cost or per document pricing
- Ability to have complete control over the senders identity, email etc. It must allow me to use my clients email address as the sender.
- Ability to have unlimited senders(users) each with their own business identity that I can set in the API.  My clients will send documents to THEIR clients. e.g. Our software -> client -> client.
- Ability to require hand drawn signatures on mobile device
- Ability to send a SMS with a url for signing
- Ability to create a document on the fly by uploading a exiting PDF and setting the field values
- Ability to have users sign in a iframe
- Webhooks for getting events of signing

The problem with most of the services I've explored is that they all seem to be geared towards the client using the API for themselves with the clients own inhouse software. I can't seem to find a API for clients using our software  where the client can use it for THEIR clients. And I can't find a service that allows me to force hand drawn signatures on mobile device other than docusign which is extremely expensive.

Any recommendations would be great!

Answer (score 5):

You specify quite many requirements the software you need must fullfill, however
one of the most important requirement is left out:
What kind of signature is required and what is the purpose of the signature.

The (european [eIDAS](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv:OJ.L_.2014.257.01.0073.01.ENG) and swiss [ZertEs](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20131913/index.html)) law distinguishes between three different kinds of signatures:

1. electronic signature
2. advanced electronic signature
3. qualified electronic signature (QES)

Each type of signature bears more legal weight, but only the QES is regarded as equivalent to the handwritten signature. Digital signatures however have nothing to do with any image of a handwritten signature inserted into the document, as they certify the integrity of the document and consent of the signee using cryptographic, certificate based signing that is usually embedded into the document (eg. PadES in PDF).

Having done quite a lot of research of service providers in this field, 
I recommend you to look closely which kind of signature they offer (eg. how much
weight the signature has in law and wether it is applicable in your jurisdiction) and what kind of signature (or maybe just act of approval) you need. Depending on your usecase, you might not need any digital signature in this sense at all. After all, you can order online just by clicking on the 'Buy' button and not by signing your order using QES and sending it to the merchant.

Unfortunately I cannot help you in finding a provider which matches all of your requirements.

However I think if you come to the conclusion, that you do not need 
"electronic signatures" as I described them, you will find that most requirements can 
be solved by creating the software yourself and using other providers for eg. the sms functionality.

If you come to the conclusion that you indeed need a signature equivalent to a handwritten signature (eg. in europe for medical receipts), I am unfortunately not aware of a provider fullfilling all of your requirements. Out of personal experience I can recommend [Skribble](https://skribble.com/), however it will not meet all of your requirements, as it will only take care of the digital signing act (QES), and not the UX and notification features you require.

[Disclaimer: I am not employed or affiliated with Skribble]

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign supports all your requirements out of the box including sending signing links via SMS.

Free developers accounts at developers.docusign.com

(I work for DocuSign.)

Comment: Requiring hand drawn signatures can be controlled by a parameter in the API?   Also, docusign is very expensive for API and doesn't have per document signing price plan.   It looks like only the $300 monthly plan offers the ability to brand.